# How can I know the source of an iframe when it is unknown when I inspect a website?

Tags: css, iframe, src

I'm changing the way a website looks by using CSS, and creating a [userstyle](https://userstyles.org) for this [webpage](http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/addmsg/2199/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94/%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A4). (Among others in its domain.)

Check out the button and its popup right next to it in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7cDU.png).
I want to change the way that popup iframe looks. But as you can see in
[this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbxI2.png) of Chrome's developer inspection tool, the src property of the iframe is unknown:
`<iframe id="cke_48_frame" class="cke_panel_frame" role="presentation" frameborder="0"`***`src(unknown)>`***

As far as I've searched Google and Stack Overflow, I found that I have to apply CSS to the actual webpage that the iframe contains. But how can I know the webpage within the iframe when the src property is unknown?

I couldn't find any info about how I can deal with this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.